# If there is a X class don't add a new Y class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little confused with my JS (I am very new working with JS).

I already have

```
$('#left-nav-menu').hover(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('menu-desktop_open_hover')
});
```

I would like to achieve if there already is this class  "menu-desktop_open_hover" and you click on the DIV with this class "menu-desktop_open_hover"  DO NOT add a new class called "menu-desktop_open"

By default when you click the DIV with the class "menu-desktop_open_hover" it is adding a new class called "menu-desktop_open" (we need to keep this class for another things but not when the div is mouse-over/mouse-out)

Do anyone know how could I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery `hasClass()`

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
  if ( $(this).hasClass("menu-desktop_open_hover") ) {
     //Do something if it's true the class is applied...
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to the toxic community (I didn't do it). I don't understand why you have  negative vote too. I am going to check your code right now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ProEvilz

Below my final code and it is working!

```js
$('#left-nav-menu').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-desktop_open_hover')
  }
);

$('#left-nav-menu').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("menu-desktop_open_hover")) {
    $("#left-nav-menu").removeClass("menu-desktop_open");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle like this:

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
  if ( $(this).hasClass("menu-desktop_open_hover") ) {
     $(this).toggleClass("menu-desktop_open");  // toggleClass() will help you.
  }
});
```